# What software can I use to e file a provisional?

Tags: provisional-application

I'm having a tremendous amount of difficulty getting the electronic filling system to accept my application.
I'm using Open Office and Microsoft Office Word to create documents and convert them to PDF's. Neither one is being accepted by the USPTO efile system.
Does anyone have any advice at all?

Comment: I don't know about the uspto, so I'm just guessing. Are there maybe format requirements like 12 points, 1,5 spacing and 3 cm to the left?

Comment: I opened the file to fix what they wanted and it started randomly adding pages and deleting pages. I don't know how to fix this and I'm very frustrated. It can't be this difficult.

Comment: What error did you get when you tried to submit your application? Also, when you say "it started randomly adding pages", what is it? Your word processor? A PDF editor?

Comment: Four errors, three were fonts being wrong, that was in the USPTO forms. The fourth was that the last page number was not the same as the number of pages. I can fix those. I have no idea about embedding or flattening, I'll look into that. The same response page that gave me the rejection reasons also had a link to my original uploaded file. When I opened this file the wonky page adding and disappearing began. I'd had a very long and frustrating day with this, I'm nearly computer illiterate when it comes to doing anything more complicated than email. I'll just make the corrections in my original

Answer (score 0):

Common problems when uploading to EFS-Web include:

1) page size: make sure you are within the limits (8.5x11 inches or DIN A4)

2) fonts: all fonts used in the document must be embedded in the pdf

3) layers: make sure you have flattened your pdf prior to upload

Source and more information: 
uspto.gov/sites/default/files/ebc/portal/efs/pdf-creation.pd‌​f

Comment: Is there a sorce for these or do you know from personal experience? Is there maybe a source on the uspto (or another) website stating these requierements? Ayways, thank you for your input and welcome to Ask Patents.

Comment: PDF guidelines and requirements: https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/ebc/portal/efs/pdf-creation.pdf